# Matlab code for finding exact solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I am trying to find an exact solution to this problem
$$y''=\frac18(32+2x^3-yy')$$
and I get "Warning: Unable to find symbolic solution."

What is my mistake?

```
% define symbolic variables
syms y(x)
eqn = diff(y,2) == (1/8)*(32+(2*x^3)-y*diff(y))
% Solution without initial conditions
sol = dsolve(eqn)
% Define initial conditions
conds = [y(1) == 17, y(3) == 43/3]
% Get solution with initial conditions
sol_conds = dsolve(eqn, conds)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use Maple or Mathematica. Solution is complicated.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a symbolic solution? You can integrate once term-wise and get a Riccati equation. Most of them do not have a symbolic solution. You have a better chance if one particular solution is known, as then a reduction to a Bernoulli equation and then to a linear equation exists.

Comment: Differential equations are hard, even for computers.

Comment: I am not sure if it has a symbolic solution, but I want to make sure I don't make any code mistakes that make the solution not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try your code to solve  the differential equation:
$$y''=-\frac18 yy'$$

```
  eqn = diff(y,2) == -(1/8)*y*diff(y))
```

Because if you integrate the original DE you get  Riccati's differential equation and most of the time it can't be integrated as Lutz Lehmann has pointed in the comment.

Comment: Thank you to all of you. I find your comments really helpful.

Comment: you're  welcome @Nan33

Comment: It's ***Riccati***. The Italian word “ricatti” is the plural of “ricatto”, that is, *blackmail*.

Comment: @egreg Thanks I have corrected it .

Comment: @user577215664 Thanks! Whenever I see it, I shiver. 

Answer (score 3):

The code looks fine. But there is no guarantee that a symbolic solution exists with the functions and solution methods coded into Matlab.

You can comment out the lines asking for a symbolic solution and have Matlab solve just the problem with the initial conditions. If your code is good, you should get a (numerically determined) solution.

Answer (score 2):

The ODE to be solved is

$$y''(x) -\frac{1}{8} \left(2 x^3+32-y(x) y'(x)\right)=0\tag{1}$$

Integrating once gives the first integral

$$y'(x) - \frac{x^4}{16}-4x+\frac{y(x)^2}{16} = c\tag{2}$$

where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Just to give you an impression here is the solution for the initial conditions $y(0)=y'(y)=0$ obtained by Mathematica from integrating the first integral with $c=0$

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\left(16+x^3+\frac{384}{e^{\frac{x^3}{24}} x \left(x^2 E_{\frac{1}{3}}\left(\frac{x^3}{24}\right)-4\ 3^{2/3} \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)-24}\right)\tag{3}$$

Here $E_{a}(z)$ is the [exponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) and $\Gamma(z)$ is the [Euler gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

An approximation with a relative error of less than 6.5% is

$$f(x) \simeq x^2\left(\frac{ x^3+32}{x^3+16}\right)\tag{4}$$